# Cassandra queries without allow filtering

Tags: cassandra

I'm beginner with Cassandra and I'm trying to execute queries without allow filtering clause.

I've created 2 tables: car parts and orders:

```
CREATE TABLE Autosale.parts 
(
    part_number text, 
    part_name text,
    matching_model text,
    condition text,
    description text,
    price double,

    PRIMARY KEY (part_number, matching_model, condition, part_name)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (matching_model ASC, condition ASC,  part_name ASC);

SELECT * 
FROM parts 
WHERE matching_model ='x'; //without allow filtering

SELECT * FROM parts WHERE condition ='x';
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE part_name ='x';
```

```
CREATE TABLE Autohandel.zamowienia 
(
    nr_of_order int,
    id_customer uuid,
    price_total double,
    parts_name set<text>,
    collect_way text,
    if_paid boolean,
    additional_requests text,
    adress text,
    customer_name text,

    PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, customer_name, nr_of_order, if_paid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (customer_name ASC, nr_of_order ASC,  if_paid ASC);


SELECT * FROM parts WHERE customer_name = 'x'; 
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE nr_of_order = 'x';
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE if_paid = true;
```

I tried using WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY and MATERIALIZED VIEW but there are another errors such as clustering order or primary key column cannot be restricted.

I will be glad for any help.

Comment: read first chapters from this free book to understand how model data for cassandra: https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how Cassandra retrieves data for you. For that you need to understand how Cassandra stores data. For example in your below case

```
CREATE TABLE Autosale.parts (
    part_number text, 
    part_name text,
    matching_model text,
    condition text,
    description text,
    price double,
PRIMARY KEY (part_number, matching_model, condition, part_name)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (matching_model ASC, condition ASC,  part_name ASC);
```

You created a table parts with `PRIMARY KEY` as `(part_number, matching_model, condition, part_name)`. Now we try to understand how primary key is defined. Generally primary key is consist of `(Partition key, List of Clutering keys)`. So in your example `part_number` is the partition key and `matching_model, condition, part_name` are two clustering keys.

Now Cassandra uses partition key for grouping same kind of rows. For example, all parts with part_number "XYZ" will be grouped together. One part can have matching_model as "ABC" and part_name as "Horn" and condition as "Good". Second part with same part_number can have matching_model as "DEF" and part_name as "Mirror" and Condition as  "Bad".

Now looking at your queries

```
Select * from parts where matching_model ='x'; //without allow filtering
Select * from parts where condition ='x';
Select * from parts where part_name ='x';
```

You want to read from `parts` table without using partition key `part_number`. Cassandra will complain because it needs partition key to respond key in optimized way. It says something like this

`Bad Request: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING`

So I would recommend you study the data modelling in Cassandra, understand the primary key, importance of partition key while querying. You might have to redesign your data model.